# How to change the size of Image.network in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, web, request

I use `Image.network("image_url")` to display images from the web in my flutter app,

I tried changing the height of the image as such: `Image.network("image_url", height: 45)`

But it doesn't work,

If anyone knows how to change the size of an image using this widget, thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you include more details about parent widget?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I was wrapping my image in container with a fixed height, my bad.

Answer (score -1):

This is works for me

---

```
 Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9,height: 100.0,width: 50.0,)
```